# How to multiply the radical expressions and simplify your answer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, multiplicative-function

I am trying to multiply and simplify the following radical expression.

$$(\sqrt{x}+5 - 4)(\sqrt{x}+5+4)$$

According to the book, the answer is $x - 11$

However, I am confused about how this even works. I tried using the following calculator that shows all the steps. http://www.softmath.com/math-com-calculator/adding-matrices/multiply-radical-expressions.html#c=simplify_algstepssimplify&v217=%2528%25u221Ax%2B5%2520-%25204%2529%2528%2520%25u221Ax%2B5%2B4%2529

However, the answer is completely different when using the calculator $x + 10\sqrt{x} + 9$.

I know I must be missing something here and it is probably something simple. I can simplify radicals by themselves with no problem, but when they are multiplied that is when I get into trouble.

Comment: The book's answer corresponds to this product $$\left(\sqrt{x+5}-4\right)\left(\sqrt{x+5}+4\right)$$ but you entered $$\left(\sqrt{x}+5-4\right)\left(\sqrt{x}+5+4\right)$$ into the calculator. See the difference?

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something simple.

Answer (score 5):

You have:
$$(\sqrt{x+5}-4)(\sqrt{x+5}+4)$$
Your lack of collecting the $+5$ under the square root is why your calculator procured the incorrect answer.

Instead, use Difference of Two Squares here:
$$(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$$ (achievable by expanding)

Comment: I knew I was missing something stupidly simple. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem. Always have to be careful when displaying math in calculators.